# SUM Until Certain Value is Reached Based on Criteria Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I have a dataset where I am manually summing $ values of Sales Orders to reach a Target $ amount. I would like to automate this process as much as possible, instead of manually going down the table and highlighting.

I have a SUMIF function in a helper column that gives me most of what I am looking for, however, I would like it to be more finely tuned.

For example, if my Target amount is $10,000 and I have Five Sales Orders at $3,000 and One Sales Order at $1,000, is it possible to select 3x3,000 and 1x1,000 to reach my target? currently my sumif function would stop at the third 3,000.

What my current formula is showing

TARGET  $10,000

| Sales Order | Value | Helper |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3,000 | TRUE |
| 2 | 3,000 | TRUE |
| 3 | 3,000 | TRUE |
| 4 | 3,000 | FALSE |
| 5 | 3,000 | FALSE |
| 6 | 1,000 | FALSE |

TOTAL = $9,000

What I would like to see:

TARGET  $10,000

| Sales Order | Value | Helper |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3,000 | TRUE |
| 2 | 3,000 | TRUE |
| 3 | 3,000 | TRUE |
| 4 | 3,000 | FALSE |
| 5 | 3,000 | FALSE |
| 6 | 1,000 | TRUE |

TOTAL = $10,000

In the helper column, this is my formula:

=SUM(INDEX([Value],1):[@[Value]])<=10,000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a full find all combinations of a number that equal a given sum (which is somewhat complex as you see in this [article](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/find-combinations-that-equal-given-sum-excel/), but it does work in your scenario. It keeps adding numbers as long as the given number doesn't take you over your desired sum.

```
=IF(OR(SUM($B$2:B2)<=10000,SUM(SUMIFS($B$1:B1,$C$1:C1,"TRUE"),B2)<=10000),TRUE,FALSE)
```

[image]